# Call endpoint after successful stripe checkout

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to find a way after I get a successful payment on stripe to call a server endpoint to send a custom a email with data from my database.

`Frontend Code`

```
 function checkout(session) {
        stripe
          .redirectToCheckout({
            sessionId: session,
          })
          .then(function (result) {})
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
```

`backend code`

```
   const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      line_items: [
        {
          price: "MY_PLAN_ID",
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      mode: "subscription",
      success_url:
        "http://localhost:3000/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
      cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/purchase",
    });
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, checkout: session.id });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need an endpoint.
you can call a function inside your node server the handle the email.
If you intend to send the email from another server, then you'll need to setup an endpoint there, you can trigger it by sending a request with `Request` or any other package.

Comment: The `redirectToCheckout` goes to a secure stripe page then redirects to a page of my choice how can I confirm user has made payment to even call that function.

Comment: You can do this by listening to the `checkout.session.completed` webhook: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time#payment-success

Comment: like @PaulAsjes mentioned. If you are using stripe checkout you'll need to configure a webhook that will trigger the email function.

Comment: OMG thank you so much, figured it out with both your help.